# Validate a string to only contain a list of words/chars

Tags: c#, string, validation

How can I check a string so it only may contains these words/chars:

```
AND
OR
XOR
!
(
)
A
B
C
D
E
```

I got this but it only checks out if it contains it so it is a wrong setup to get what I want...

```
var logic = "A + B"; 
var exists = new[] { "(", ")", "a", "and", "b", "c", "d", "e", "or", "xor", "!" }
    .Any(c => model.logic.ToLower().Contains(c));
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is a word?

Comment: Yeah, if `(` is a "word", why is `+` not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only check if at least one of the tokens in your `string[]` is contained in the string, but you want the opposite: check if all tokens/words of the string are contained in the `string[]`.

I guess all words are separated by spaces, you can use `String.Split` to get the words:

```
string[] allowed = { "(", ")", "a", "and", "b", "c", "d", "e", "or", "xor", "!" };
string[] words = logic.Split(new char[]{}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
bool allAllowed = words.All(w => allowed.Contains(w, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: `logic`, not `login`.

Comment: @MetroSmurf: fixed

Comment: That was a weird downvote by someone; +1 to offset and for actually answering the question with the currently known info from the O.P.. :)

Comment: @MetroSmurf https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-answers-a-low-quality-off-topic-or-duplicate-qu/315939#315939

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regular expression for that. This one matches your words

```
^(?!\s*$)(?:AND|OR|XOR|!|\(|\)|A|B|C|D|E| )+$
```

[regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/) - really cool tool to play around and get what you want.